# Upload or fetch only changed Git file from central repository (GCP) to VM Server

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, git-fetch, git-ftp

We are having several client VMs that run some stuff based on config files we provide, and we store all our config files in ONE central repository in GCP.

So Suppose, whenever we change ONE config file, eg `config_file_1` we push it to that GCP central repository and then we manually go to the correspondent VM that is using this `config_file_1` and we update it
**actually VMs are using only one file from GCP central repository that we have**

eg:
VM 1 uses `config_file_1`
VM 2 uses `config_file_6`
VM 3 uses `config_file_9`

`[May be we will maintain the table which VM using which file]`

We want some mechanism to automate this stuff,
**So if we change `config_file_9` and push that changed file to GCP via GIT then automatically VM 3 should update `config_file_9`**

Things that we think might help but not satisfying us:
-- may be using GCP PubSub, we will have subscriber on each VM (but seems complicated)
-- using may be `git-ftp` (don't know it will work or not, like in multiple VM)
-- automatic git pull/fetch particular file on VM (don't know it will work or not, like in multiple VM)

So, we need help from you, what could be the best approach to deal with this problem according to you?
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: 1) Using one Git repository for multiple VM configuration files is not a good idea. Git is a source code control system. You push and pull repositories. Although you can **fetch** a single file, your repositories (local and remote) will quickly get out of sync - unless you are only doing pulls. Then you will need to write a GitHub WebHook to notify the VM that the repository has changed.

Comment: 2) I recommend storing your configuration files on Google Cloud Storage. Then just copy the file needed by the VM during VM startup script or manually via a shell script. If you need auto update then you will need to implement some form of Cloud Storage Event to notify the VM of file change.

Answer (score 1):

"1) Using one Git repository for multiple VM configuration files is not a good idea. Git is a source code control system. You push and pull repositories. Although you can fetch a single file, your repositories (local and remote) will quickly get out of sync - unless you are only doing pulls. Then you will need to write a GitHub WebHook to notify the VM that the repository has changed.

2. I recommend storing your configuration files on Google Cloud Storage. Then just copy the file needed by the VM during VM startup script or manually via a shell script. If you need auto update then you will need to implement some form of Cloud Storage Event to notify the VM of file change."

- @John Hanley.